# Oracle replace some duplicated characters (non digits )

Tags: sql, string, oracle, regexp-replace

anyone can help me to build proper syntax for regexp_replace to remove any multiplicated non-digits and non-letters from string ? If digit/letter is multiplicated - it is not changed
eg.
source and expected result:

```
'ABBC000001223,  ABC00000212,,, '
'ABBC000001223, ABC00000212, '
```

(removed second occurance of space after comma and second and third comma )

Answer (score 2):

Use this `REGEXP_REPLACE` to match any non alphanumeric character in the first group

```
 ([^[:alnum:]])
```

followed by one or more same charcters (group 1)

```
 ([^[:alnum:]])(\1)+
```

and replace it with the original character (group 1)

I added some other data to demonstrate the result

```
with dta as (
select 'ABBC000001223,  ABC00000212,,, ' txt from dual union all
select ',.,;,;;;;,,,,,,,,,,,,#''++`´' txt from dual union all
select 'ABBC000001223ABC00000212' txt from dual)
select txt,
regexp_replace(txt,'([^[:alnum:]])(\1)+', '\1') result
from dta
 

TXT
-------------------------------
RESULT
--------------------------------
ABBC000001223,  ABC00000212,,,  
ABBC000001223, ABC00000212,     
,.,;,;;;;,,,,,,,,,,,,#'++`´     
,.,;,;,#'+`´

ABBC000001223ABC00000212        
ABBC000001223ABC00000212
```